# Dereferencing a double-level pointer results in different behaviour from dereferencing a single-level pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse-engineering, memory-editing

Version 1:

```
int* work(int** pointer, int offset)
{
    return *pointer + (offset/sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int** pointer = (int**) 0x4df73c;
    int offset = 0xf4;

    int* healthLowestPointer = work(pointer, offset);

    while(true) {
        *healthLowestPointer = 1000;
        Sleep(250);
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
int* work(int* pointer, int offset)
{
    return (int*) (*pointer + (offset/sizeof(int)));
}

int main()
{    
    int* pointer = (int*) 0x4df73c;
    int offset = 0xf4;

    int* healthLowestPointer = work(pointer, offset);

    while(true) {
        *healthLowestPointer = 1000;
        Sleep(250);
    }
}
```

Version 1 works correctly, but version 2 doesn't seem to. I don't understand why version 2 is broken. Isn't dereferencing a a double-level pointer the same thing as dereferencing a single-level pointer i.e. it grabs the value at the memory address the pointer contains?

How would I write a function that takes a n-level pointer as input, and returns a 1-level pointer by dereferencing the n-level pointer n-1 times?

Comment: Both versions are UB.

Comment: Good night SO, no more of these questions today... /OFF

Comment: @Armin: I'm not sure what you mean. Version 1 is consistent and always works.

Comment: @user2327287 You are trying to write on unreserved memory. working != correct.

Comment: @Armin: The memory I am editing has been already allocated. I am editing a memory of another application using DLL injection. This is just a simplified example.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that next time.

Comment: @user2327287 I guess on your system sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*)

Comment: @user2327287 Your simplified versions are both undefined behavior.  Your *real* versions *may* be undefined behavior, but we can only comment on what you're allowing us to see.  Keep in mind that "consistent and always works" is a behavior, so you might be asking why an undefined behavior could be *that* behavior

Comment: @john: I just checked and they are both size 4.

Comment: @user2327287 It like everyone says, this isn't the real code. I'm not at all surprised this code crashes. Why one version of your real code works and the other doesn't is hard to say without seeing the real code.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Real version: http://pastie.org/private/qekgrjbewcg33rsq9baexw

Comment: @john: Neither crash. The second version just edits the value of the wrong memory address and instead of changing my health to 1000 it sets my y-position in game to 1000.

Comment: I am injecting the DLL into a game called Assault Cube (cubers.net)

Comment: @user2327287 Well sftrabbit figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very different things. An `int**` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. If you dereference it, you get an `int*`. An `int*` is a pointer to an `int`. If you dereference it, you get an `int`.

In the first example, you pass an `int**` with value `0x4df73c` as the first argument to `work`. You then dereference this, which should give you an `int*`. That is, `0x4df73c` is the address of an address and doing `*pointer` has gotten you the second addess. You then do pointer arithmetic with this `int*` by adding `(offset/sizeof(int))`, which works out how many `int`s there are with `offset` bytes. So when you add this value, your `int*` will move along to point at the `int` at that offset. You then return this `int*` and all is well.

In the second example, you pass `0x4df73c` as an `int*`. You then dereference it, which gives you an `int`. Now the `+` doesn't do pointer arithmetic - it does integer arithmetic. `(offset/sizeof(int))` will still give you the number of `int`s in `offset` bytes, but the arithmetic won't do what you want. It won't increase the value of the `int` by the appropriate amount.

Let's say an `int` is 4 bytes on your machine. When you have an `int*` called `p` and you do `p + 5`, this doesn't just add `5` to the address in `p`. It adds `5` times the size of an `int` (20 bytes), so that it's now pointing at the 5th `int`. However, if you have an `int` called `i` and you do `i + 5`, this really does just add `5`.

So that's your problem. When you add to the `int`, **you're not doing the appropriate arithmetic**. I imagine it *would* work if you change it to, assuming an `int*` and an `int` are the same size on your system (as you say they are):

```
return (int*) (*pointer + offset);
```

but I *do not recommend this*. Don't use an `int` as though it were a pointer. The cast to the `(int*)` involves a `reinterpret_cast` and is horrible. Stick to your first code.

Comment: Is there a reason why reinterpret_cast is bad besides the fact that the second version is more confusing/cryptic for someone that is trying to read the code?

Comment: @user2327287 It's bad because the standard leaves much of its behaviour undefined. Pretty much the only well-defined thing you can do with `reinterpret_cast` is cast from `T*` to some other `U*` and then back to `T*` and be guaranteed that it still works. Everything else leaves the realm of reason. You're basically assuming that interpreting an `int` as an `int*` is an okay thing, which it usually is not.

Comment: Is it equally bad to interpert `int**` as `int*`?

Comment: @user2327287 It's equally undefined. You're more likely to get away with it, but just don't do it. An `int**` is certainly not an `int*`.

Comment: @user2327287 Nothing, it was a just a little joke about sleeping.

Comment: Is there any good way to dereference a n-level pointer instead of overloading as done here: http://pastie.org/private/idziv2h7xlaetit2yrciq?

Comment: @user2327287 This doesn't make sense. Why would you even want to do that? I think you have some big misunderstandings about pointers. Don't make functions for dereferencing, use the dereference operator.

Comment: The application that I want to edit in memory uses dynamic memory allocation. Using a debugger, cheat engine, and other tools, I can find a static pointer (up to 8-levels) that points to the value that I need to edit. Instead of doing `********pointer` every time I want to edit it, I'd much rather simplify it to `*pointer`.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic and integer arithmetic are not the same thing.

Ignoring the issue of whether writing to the locations you are using is valid, consider the result of these:

```
int i=5;
int j=i+1; // now j==6
int* pi = &i; // let's say pi is 0x1000
int* pj = &i+1 // now pj is 0x1000 + (sizeof int)
```